# Convert column to dataframe column geaders

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have the following pandas dataframe

|  | Study_Identification | Study_Identification_Old | Study_Identification_New |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Unique Protocol ID: | XXX | AAA |
| 1 | Brief Title: | YYY | BBB |

I would like it to be converted to a pandas dataframe with one row. Is there a simple way to do it. I tried pivot but was getting weird results.

| Unique Protocol ID:Study_Identification_Old | Unique Protocol ID:Study_Identification_New | Brief Title:Study_Identification_Old | Brief Title:Study_Identification_New |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXX | AAA | YYY | BBB |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pivot, swap the level of columns names, shift values up to fill NaN values and flatten column names:

```
out = df.pivot(columns='Study Identification').swaplevel(0,1,axis=1).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values)).fillna('')
out.columns = s.columns.map(''.join)
```

Answer (score 0):

So in your case reshape the df with `unstack`

```
s = df.set_index('A',append=True).unstack(level=1).swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)
s.columns = s.columns.map(''.join)
```